# Dictionary or list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, time-complexity

I have a usecase, where I need to store geographical coordinates(latitudes and longitudes) and the distance of those coordinates from a particular fixed point.
I can do this by:

1. Creating a list of tuples as [(lat1,long1,distance),(lat2,long2,distance),(lat3,long3,distance),....]
   OR
2. Creating a dictionary with coordinates tuples as key and corresponding distance of each coordinate as values {(lat1,long1):distance,(lat2,long2):distance,(lat3,long3):distance,......}

My business use case requires me to fetch the first 10 coordinates with minimum distance from the fixed point, which requires sorting based on distance.

Question - So which data structure would be best for this sorting use case, a dictionary or a list of tuples? I know dictionaries are good for O(1) time complexity when we know the exact key we need to fetch the value of. But for this scenario of sorting based on distance, would I see any performance benefit by storing the details in a dictionary vs a list of tuples?

Comment: _"would I see any performance benefit"_: No you wouldn't. Regular dictionaries don't even keep track of order, so `{'key1': 'value1', 'key2', 'value2'}` is the same as `{'key2': 'value2', "key1': 'value1'}`, so you'd end up getting the values of the dict as a list anyway.

Comment: I think in your case that dictionaries would be preferable for your case because you could immediately call the key (distance), you wouldn't see much performance difference, but the code could be a bit more compact

Comment: If the set of points is fixed, you can simply keep a list sorted by distance and get the first 10 elements. If you'll be adding and deleting points over time, use a *priority queue* (a recipe for implementing one can be found in the documentation of the `heapq` module).

Comment: @Ironkey A dict lets you get a single point *given* a distance(or a distance given a point, depending the direction of the mapping). The OP wants the 10 *smallest* distances.